# Is there a Tiefling counterpart to the Pathfinder Player Companion Blood of Angels?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, books, tiefling

The Pathfinder Player Companion Blood of Angels goes into detail on Aasimar with background, points of view, extra rules for different subtypes, a pair of charts to randomise your character and so on.

So I was wondering, is there a Player Companion that does this exact thing but for Tieflings instead of Aasimar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## There is.

It is called [Blood of Fiends](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Blood_of_Fiends).